# I am struggling to set an API up for my existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am getting a Routing Error : `"uninitialized constant Api::V1::TopicsController"` even though i have the routes :

```
namespace :api do #, constraints: { format: "json" }
namespace :v1 do
resources :topics, only: [:index, :show]
end
end
```

and i can see the routes:

```
api_v1_topics_path GET /api/v1/topics(.:format)
api_v1_topic_path GET /api/v1/topics/:id(.:format)
```

I am trying to get a json responce using postman or curl

```
curl --user "example5@railstutorial.org:password" http://hostbubble.org:3000/api/v1/topics
```

but it wont even recognise the controller exists. I cant see where i have gone wrong.

Would love to get past this.
Many thanks

Comment: have you created the controller?  If so, show the code for it.

Comment: While it might seem reduntant you should probally specify that you checked the obvious stuff like ensuring that the class actually exists in `app/controllers/v1/`topics_controller.rb` and that its not just programmer error such as a typo or VC issue.